# How can I calculate mean target registration error (mTRE) for 2d/3d image?

Tags: python

For a given 3D point set P1(x, y, z), the registered point set P2(x, y, z) is obtained through T transformation, and then projected into the 2D space P3(x, y), and then calculate the error with the 2D target point set P4(x, y). There are two questions: how to project the point set in 3D space onto 2D space? And, how to transform the point set in 3D space through T transformation? T is a rigid transformation, including rotation and translation.

P2 = T(P1) = P1 * T, P3 = Proj(P2), mTRE(P3, P4)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.